# Sum of values in a dictionary error 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I have multiple dictionaries nested within a list `mydict` and one of the keys `'dummy'` has values 0 or 1, and I want to add all of these values. I indexed the key correctly but I'm not getting the sum, the error reads `'int' object is not iterable`

```
mydict = [{'name':'John', 'dummy': 1},{'name':'Brad','dummy': 0}]    
for i in range(len(mydict)):
 print sum(mydict[i]['dummy'])
```

Since my dictionaries are nested, `mydict[i]['dummy']` is either 0 or 1, and `type(mydict[0]['dummy'])` is an integer.

I'm not sure why then I can't get the sum using the loop above.

Comment: show your `mydict`

Answer (score 2):

`sum()`expect an iterable and as you said `mydict[0]['dummy']` is an integer.

Try this:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'name':'John', 'dummy': 1},{'name':'Brad','dummy': 0}]
print sum([element['dummy'] for element in list_of_dicts ] )
```

This will create a list with the dummy values on the dict and them it will add them.

Comment: You can make that list comp a generator comp for memory efficiency as you don't need the full list of integers.

Comment: I get TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict?

Comment: I thought mydicts was a dict indexed by ints, but its a list of dicts. I changed the code and it will work with you example now.

Comment: @timgeb Could you add more information about list comp vs generator comp?